# how to scrape dynamic webpages in python without selenium for application that handle multiple users at a time

Tags: python, web-scraping

how to scrape dynamic webpages in Python without selenium for applications that handle multiple users at a time. that means I need a Python code for a server-side application without using Webdriver.
example webpage: "https://www.truemeds.in/search/naxdom"
i tried bs4 requests but they are not working.

Comment: be specific about the question. add your code that you have tried and issue that you are facing.